# Replacing json file using powershell script does not work when script is called as even/action in installshield suite

Tags: powershell, installshield

I need to replace an existing .json file on the target machine.

I am executing it as Event/Action in my Suite with elevated rights.

This is the  script:

```
try {
    $ProductName = "ravendb"
    $Product = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $ProductName }

    if ($Product) {
        Stop-Service RavenDB
        (Get-Service RavenDB).WaitForStatus('Stopped', '00:00:30')

        $Folder = 'C:\RavenDB-4.2.x\Server'
        Copy-Item -Path "settings.json" -Destination $Folder -force

        Start-Service RavenDB
        (Get-Service RavenDB).WaitForStatus('Running', '00:00:30')

        exit(0)
    }
    else {
        exit(1)
    }
}
catch {
    $StringValue = Resolve-SuiteString -StringId $_.Exception.Message
    Trace-SuiteInfo -LogMessage $StringValue
    exit(1)
}
```

But the file has actually not been overwritten. Service is being stopped/restarted though.
Running the script manually (using bypass execution policy) works fine.

Suite debug log indicates no error:

```
2-25-2023[01:26:47 PM]: Running event 'update-ravendb-settings'
2-25-2023[01:26:47 PM]: Engine: request for proxy handler, 0, 0
2-25-2023[01:26:48 PM]: (PowerShell Action): Attempting to load through CLR 4 APIs...
2-25-2023[01:26:48 PM]: (PowerShell Action): Getting meta host...
2-25-2023[01:26:48 PM]: (PowerShell Action): Enumerating available runtimes...
2-25-2023[01:26:48 PM]: (PowerShell Action): Highest available runtime: v4.0.30319
2-25-2023[01:26:48 PM]: (PowerShell Action): Trying to use highest runtime...
2-25-2023[01:26:48 PM]: (PowerShell Action): Using highest version runtime...
2-25-2023[01:26:57 PM]: Action returned value 0x00000000
2-25-2023[01:26:57 PM]: Action 'update-ravendb-settings' returned status 0x00000000
```

Why is it, that my script won't work when being called as action/event in Installhield suite?

Comment: Are you an admin?  Did you start PS by right click PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.  If you are an admin to give Admin on remote machine you need to replace the colon in the path with a dollar sign.  Try : $Folder = 'C$\RavenDB-4.2.x\Server'

Comment: note that running script manually as admin and bypassing executionpolicy works (as mentioned) but running within installer does not actually replace the file. the rest of the script works, though. still this is an interesting point. i'll try to change my script to using $ over :

Comment: Did you check Event viewer on Remote machine for errors?  Maybe the installer has different environment and the PSModulePath is different on installer than when you run.

Comment: @jdweng could you please explain how environment / PSModulePath are relevant for copying a file using copy -item? the actual file is located where the script is...

Comment: using $ over : does not solve the issue.

Comment: Don't see anything in event viewer, as I expected since script returns without any errors. Mistery remains unsolved.

Comment: Whitespace before and after `-` as part of a command name isn't allowed. E. g. instead of `Get - WmiObject` you have to write `Get-WmiObject`.

Comment: this must have been happened by formatting. code is actually without whitespaces around '-'

Comment: See following that discusses editing the json file : https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.4/csharp/start/getting-started

Comment: Thanks for the link but I don't see how this is related to my issue with powershell replacing a file.

Answer (score 0):

finally I got it working by parsing file as json and update it rather than trying to replace it:

```
        $jsonPath = 'C:\RavenDB-4.2.x\Server\settings.json'
        $jobj = Get-Content -Raw $jsonPath | ConvertFrom-Json       
        
        $prop = "Patching.MaxStepsForScript"
        
        if(!($jobj.psobject.properties.name | where{$_ -match $prop}))
        {
            stop-service RavenDB
            (Get-Service RavenDB).WaitForStatus('Stopped','00:00:30')
            
            $jobj | add-member -Name $prop -value 100000 -MemberType NoteProperty
            $jobj | ConvertTo-Json > $jsonPath      

            start-service RavenDB
            (Get-Service RavenDB).WaitForStatus('Running','00:00:30')
            
            $message="updated settings"                 
        }
```

I don't know why it works better this way but it does.